# Deleting millions of logs in batches

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, logging, transactions

I have a fast growing table with logs that I frequently have to delete (the server doesn't have much resources). It grows by at least two million entries every day. The database is a SQL Server 2012.

Currently I use this script to delete entries older than 7 days:

```
set nocount on;
declare @r int = 1
while @r > 0
begin
    begin transaction;  
        delete top(10000)   
        from [Logs]
        where 
            cast([Timestamp] as date) < cast(dateadd(day, -7, GETUTCDATE()) as date))
        set @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
    commit transaction;
end
```

When I don't do it daily then it runs for a couple of hours (3-5) *blocking* other tasks that usually exit with timeouts (they need it for reporting).

I use transactions because I sometimes need to stop it before it's finished and this is easier to do with smaller batches. Otherwise there is too much to rollback.

The table is a pretty *normal* log:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Environment] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Logger] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

---

Is there a way to make this script faster? Am I doing anything terribly wrong here?

Comment: How about computing `cast(dateadd(day, -7, GETUTCDATE()) as date)` once and reuse it?

Comment: @Heslacher I like it, definitely will improve readability... I'll check whether the execution plan would change too.

Comment: If this is a production environment, I would suggest to use a commercial tool that handles billions of logs for you: https://www.splunk.com/

Comment: If a commercial tool is not an option, consider creating an unclustered index on [Timestamp].

Comment: @dfhwze I'll take a look at that tool. Can it handle deleting too? I cannot even query the table when it grows over ~10mln rows (yeah, it's for production)

Comment: @dfhwze I'm reluctant about creating an index for it because I'm afraid with that insert ratio it might hurt performance there. I'll need to test it first how many inserts the database can manage with an index on the `Timestamp` column.

Comment: Check out these tools. They allow for very fast lookup, with date range, string pattern, regex filters, even if you have billions of records. I strongly suggest your company investigates the option of moving logs out of your own database and into the cloud.

Comment: @dfhwze we are using an ancient sql server that cannot even handle 10mln logs. Unfortunatelly a cloud will not gonna happen :-( everyone knows, nobody cares.

Comment: Then they will find out the hard way that at some point, this will be unmanagable :/

Comment: @dfhwze it already is... that's why I need this script.

Comment: if there is a quality environment with an equivalent load on the database, you could test the index there.

Comment: some other options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log -> it also depends on whether you are deleting most of the records from the table, or keeping most.

Comment: @dfhwze I have an idea! I'll put all ids that I want to delete into a `cts` and then make a delete + join with that on the index without searching each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another recent Code Review question that has a lot of similarities to yours: [Daily SQL job to delete records older than 24 hours](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/225674/47529).

I think I would recommend three things here:

1. Snapshot isolation
2. Not using `TOP`
3. Doing the work in another table

---

### Snapshot isolation

[Snapshot isolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) is a really cool tool that effectively prevents most things from blocking readers. As a result, even if your delete is running long, report-writers can still hit your table and they'll see the most recent, valid data. Then once your delete finishes, they'll start seeing the data without your deleted rows. This lets you do whatever you need to do without having to worry as much about end-users. It doesn't make your code faster, but it will somewhat reduce the need for it to be.

---

### Not using `TOP`

Because you're using `TOP`, you effectively force all of the data to be re-sorted every time. Additionally, `TOP` will usually introduce [row goals](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.html). This isn't necessarily a bad thing, but it may choose less-ideal plans in the interest of getting a subset of rows as quickly as possible.

Because your `Id` column is an indexed `IDENTITY` column, **and** because we're deleting the oldest data (I'm assuming you don't generally update old data), you can do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM [Logs]
  WHERE Id BETWEEN @LowestCurrentIndex AND @HighestCurrentIndex
    AND CAST([Timestamp] AS date) < CAST(DATEADD( DAY, -7, GETUTCDATE()) AS date);
```

This assumes you can maintain `@LowestCurrentIndex` and `@HighestCurrentIndex` as the range of values to currently consider. This will get you nice index accesses as well.

A potential enhancement is to get a separate table that has all potentially affected rows, like so:

```
SELECT Id
  INTO #OldData
  FROM [Logs]
  WHERE CAST([Timestamp] AS date) < CAST(DATEADD( DAY, -7, GETUTCDATE()) AS date);
```

Then you can just join between the two (and if you have an index on `#OldData.Id` it'll be a great merge-join) with the same bounds logic.

```
DELETE [Logs]
  FROM [Logs]
    INNER JOIN #OldData OldData
      ON [Logs].Id = OldData.Id
  WHERE OldData.Id BETWEEN @LowestCurrentIndex AND @HighestCurrentIndex -- This could be on either table
```

---

### Do the work in another table

If copying the data is less expensive than deleting it (very possible), then you may be able to more efficiently do the work with less user interruptions by doing all of your work in a separate table, and then switching the tables. Broadly speaking, the workflow would look like this:

1. Copy all of the *valid* data into another identically formatted table (same indices, constraints, etc)
2. Truncate the original table
3. Perform a partition switch

Alternatively, if partition switching isn't your jam, you can do a very similar thing manually:

1. Copy all of the *valid* data into another identically formatted table (same indices, constraints, etc)
2. Rename the original table to something else
3. Rename the table from #1 to the original table's name
4. Truncate the original (now renamed) table from #2

These will result in much less index maintenance, and many of the operations can be done via minimal logging if well structured.

Comment: wow, this is a lot of interesting stuff! It'll take some time to study it and do experiments. I'll let you know when I implemented these suggestions.