# Daily SQL job to delete records older than 24 hours

Tags: sql, datetime, time-limit-exceeded, sql-server, t-sql

Below is a delete job to delete 1M+ records daily and takes 13 hours to complete and sometimes more than that. I need to optimize this.

> The table *tblcalldatastore* is being inserted 24*7 through a stored
>   procedure and is supposed to have no records older than 24 hours.

[image]

Execution plan is below.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryYi2Sv7B

```
BEGIN      

SET NOCOUNT ON;      

DECLARE @DELETECOUNT int      
DECLARE @DELETEATATIME int      

DECLARE @CutOffDate datetime      
DECLARE @HourRetained smallint      
set @HourRetained = 24      
begin Try      


set @CutOffDate = getutcdate()      

select  @DELETECOUNT = count(*) from [tblcalldatastore]      
where  istestcase=0      
and datediff(hour,receiveddate,@CutOffDate)>@HourRetained      

SET @DELETEATATIME = 20000      





WHILE @DELETECOUNT > 0      

BEGIN      

DELETE TOP(@DELETEATATIME) FROM tblcalldatastore WITH (ROWLOCK)  WHERE IsTestCase=0 and datediff(hour,receiveddate,@CutOffDate)>@HourRetained       


SET @DELETECOUNT = @DELETECOUNT - @DELETEATATIME       


END      




end try      


BEGIN CATCH      

SELECT 'FAILED - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage      

END CATCH      

END
```

Comment: Are you retaining more data than you delete, and which is the ratio of retained/deleted?

Comment: I am deleting any record older than 24 hours and the job runs daily.

Comment: Have you tested performance of copying data of a single day to a temporary table, truncating the target table, and re-inserting the copied data back to the target table?

Comment: Yes, it's not taking much time to copy or insert, it is taking time to delete and select. One of the column has huge XML string.

Comment: Execution plan - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryYi2Sv7B

Comment: Here's a similar problem also experiencing 90+ % on non-clustered index. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189607/delete-millions-of-rows-from-a-sql-table

Comment: Please ensure that your code is posted with the intended formatting. There seems to be a lot of code here that isn't correctly commented out.

Comment: Also tell us more about exactly what this code is designed to accomplish, and what the schema looks like. It's hard to help you without that background information. See [ask].

Comment: @200_success - I have updated the code. The code is designed to delete any record older than 24 hours on daily basis.

Comment: I'm hardly an SQL expert, but this doesn't happen to iterate over every entry on each deletion-cycle (20,000 entries) again, does it? As in, if a cycle is complete, start from the beginning. If it does, stop doing that.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a smaller database to test the exact workings of your query on and note the inefficiencies. This will allow you to test alternative implementations a lot easier and faster.

Comment: An obvious improvement would be to set `@CutOffDate` to be now - 24 hours, then simply `delete from table where received < @CutOffDate`.  Or am I missing some subtlety of T-SQL that's different to standard SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From Comments

*Have you tested performance of copying data of a single day to a temporary table, truncating the target table, and re-inserting the copied data back to the target table?*

> *Yes, it's not taking much time to copy or insert, it is taking time to delete and select. One of the column has huge XML string.*

### Proposed Solution

Since inserting and copying data does not seem to yield a performance penalty, I would suggest to:

- copy to data of today to a staging table
- truncate the existing table (much faster than delete, no transaction logs)
- copy staged data back to existing table

Or alternatively, as Dannnno suggests:

*Potentially faster than copying the data twice would be to copy data to a staging table, truncate the existing table, then rename them both to swap places. This minimizes latches required for DDL, and also only requires a single copy. Snapshot isolation would also help this be as non-invasive as possible for anyone hitting the database.*

#### Links

- [Similar problem: non-clustered index bottleneck on delete](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189607/delete-millions-of-rows-from-a-sql-table)
- [Enlists a couple of possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log)

Comment: The solution seems perfect to me! All I need is to find out best possible time slot when the Production is not in use.

Comment: Potentially faster than copying the data twice would be to copy data to a staging table, truncate the existing table, then rename them both to swap places. This minimizes latches required for DDL, and also only requires a single copy. Snapshot isolation would also help this be as non-invasive as possible for anyone hitting the database.

Comment: @Dannnno Can I include your suggestion in my answer as an alternative option? Or you want to make an answer yourself?

Comment: Feel free to include it yourself; it doesn't add a whole lot of additional information

Comment: @Dannnno I added it because comments can get removed, thanks for sharing your views.